# OpenVPN как dll для использования в проекте

Tags: c++, openvpn

Можно каким-то образом подключить openvpn к своему проекту, как библиотеку и как его в дальнейшем использовать?

Проект пишется на С ++ под виндовс.

Если вопрос уже где-то описано, или по каким либо причинам вы голосуете против, то напишите в комментариях ссылки на источник информации или причину голосования против.

Как собрать openvpn.dll для виндовс из исходных кодов openVPN?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803582/compile-openvpn-or-softether-as-dll-for-use-in-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: @Мирон Сосяк  Вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: @0andriy в тому питанні немає відповіді

Comment: Почему же? Есть ответ, что человек бросил затею. Отрицательный результат — тоже результат.

Comment: Это было год назад, может уже есть решение.

Comment: Если у вас получится -- опубликуйте.